# BlackBerry Jabber/XMPP basic library

Tags: blackberry, xmpp

I am looking for a simple BlackBerry Jabber/XMPP basic library. Please tell me where i can find a good free open source library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one, maybe: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jxa/ I haven't tried it myself. I can't tell if it's good. Sorry.